# Launching app built with electron doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, electron

**Here's my problem :**

I am learning electron, and wanted to know how things goes when building an app with electron. So i decided to clone an existing application which use electron to see what happens. All went good, no errors when building the .exe. Then, I install the application with the generated installer. And when I launched the app, ... nothing. No errors, task manager says the app is running but no windows.

**I tried that :**

To see if the problem isn't the code itself (which should work because it's a popular app), I launched the app with npm start (electron-webpack dev if I remember correctly) and all worked fine. I haven't changed the code and obviously I did npm install. Since it's not my app, I have absolutly no clue about why the app isn't working when building it. Of course, when I download the .exe on their website, it works perfectly.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "scratch-desktop",
  "productName": "Scratch Desktop",
  "description": "Scratch 3.0 as a self-contained desktop application",
  "author": "Scratch Foundation",
  "version": "3.9.0",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-webpack dev --bail --display-error-details --env.minify=false",
    "build-gui": "node ./scripts/run-in-gui.js build",
    "watch-gui": "node ./scripts/run-in-gui.js watch",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist/ ./static/assets/",
    "compile": "rimraf ./dist/ && electron-webpack --bail --display-error-details --env.minify=false",
    "fetch": "rimraf ./static/assets/ && mkdirp ./static/assets/ && node ./scripts/fetchMediaLibraryAssets.js",
    "dist": "npm run build-gui && npm run fetch && npm run compile -p && node ./scripts/electron-builder-wrapper.js",
    "dist:dir": "npm run dist -- --dir -c.compression=store -c.mac.identity=null",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --color --ext .jsx,.js ."
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@github.com/LLK/scratch-desktop.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.12",
    "scratch-gui": "github:LLK/scratch-gui#scratch-desktop"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "async": "^2.6.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^2.3.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "electron": "^6.1.7",
    "electron-builder": "^22.2.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "electron-notarize": "^0.2.1",
    "electron-store": "^3.3.0",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.7.4",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-scratch": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.2",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "lodash.bindall": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.defaultsdeep": "^4.6.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "nets": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "16.2.1",
    "react-intl": "2.4.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "upath": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7A33.png)

So, what am I doing wrong and what to do to make this app working ?

Thanks for your answers, if you have any questions, don't hesitate.

Comment: Your build configuration is not working well. Whenever you try to open the dev console in prod app. Then it will display the error why it is not rendering.

Comment: Maybe, at least the app couldn't find the entry ```index.html```

Comment: Can you post with your package.json and the screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: @tpikachu i edited my post with the package.json and the screenshot of the project structure